# Invoking a GRPC method fails on Azure Container Apps with Dapr

Tags: azure-container-apps, dapr, grpc-dotnet

I developed a GRPC service using .NET 8. The service functions properly when run locally. However, when I deploy it to Azure Container Apps service and attempt to invoke it from another app with Dapr, I encounter the following error:

`initial http2 frame from server is not a settings frame: *http2.GoAwayFrame`

The service code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGrpcService<MyService>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
app.Run();
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./MyServiceApp/MyServiceApp.csproj", "./MyServiceApp/MyServiceApp.csproj"]
RUN dotnet restore "./MyServiceApp/MyServiceApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyServiceApp"
RUN dotnet restore "MyServiceApp.csproj"
RUN dotnet publish "MyServiceApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/out /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyServiceApp.dll"]
```

The code used from the second app:

```
var daprPort = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DAPR_GRPC_PORT");
var url = string.IsNullOrEmpty(daprPort) ? this.myServiceUrl : $"http://localhost:{daprPort}";
this.logger.LogInformation("Using service url {Url}", url);
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(url);
var client = new MyService.MyServiceClient(channel);
var myRequest = new MyRequest { DeviceId = request.DeviceId.ToString() };
var metadata = new Metadata { { "dapr-app-id", "myapp" } };
var response = await client.DoSomethingAsync(myRequest, metadata, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

The bicep fragment for the service app:

```
ingress: {
  targetPort: 8080
  external: false
  transport: 'http2'
}
dapr: {
  enabled: true
  appId: 'myapp'
  appPort: 8080
  appProtocol: 'grpc'
  enableApiLogging: true
  logLevel: 'debug'
}
```

Comment: Could you please verify your Dapr version both locally and on the Azure container?

Comment: @UtkarshDubey locally I'm running it without dapr.
On Azure Container Apps, I can find the following version in the logs:  scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.11.5-msft.1

Comment: Then, kindly create the same environment locally and include the results in your question along with more detailed logs.